# Multiple file types search using Google Custom Search API

Tags: api, search, google-custom-search

I need to get Google search results for particular filetypes.
For example, in browser I would directly google search for "**hyperloop filetype:pdf**" and it will list out PDF files for "Hyperloop".
For this, my Google Custom Search request URI will be https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=MY_UNIQUE_ID&q=hyperloop&fileType=pdf

However, currently I would like to get search results for "hyperloop" of filetypes .ppt or .doc.
In browser, I would achieve this by googling "**hyperloop filetype:ppt OR filetype:doc**".

What will be my Search request URI equivalent for this query?
I could not find anything related to querying using multiple values for a single parameter in [Google Custom Search Documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing

```
q=hyerloop&filetype=pdf
```

you can use

```
q=hyperloop%20filetype:pdf%20OR%20filetype:doc
```

Comment: That's what I have done finally. But I was looking for a solution in **&fileType=** format instead of specifying filetype in search expression. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

use this its work

```
  $url='https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCJUGIb_tevRKD-Kxxi5f4&cx=010407088:onjj7gscy2g&q='.  urlencode($keywords).'&filetype=doc&filetype=docx';
```

for me

Comment: to clarify, this answer adds &filetype=... multiple times to the query, for each of the allowed formats. Google CSE treats that as "OR"