# Multiple fileType for Google Custom Search API during image searching

Tags: google-custom-search, google-search-api, google-image-search

Currently, I'm using Google Custom Search API, to perform image searching using REST

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#request

I was wondering, what is the correct way, to specific multiple file type?

`fileType` is being mentioned briefly in the API document.

For instance, the following is the GET request, to search only `BMP` type image.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&cx=GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=picasso&searchType=image&fileType=bmp
```

However, what if I want to search both PNG and BMP image?

At first, I thought

```
fileType=png,bmp
```

might work as mentioned in http://codigogenerativo.com/code/google-custom-search-api/

However, if I test using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&cx=GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=picasso&searchType=image&fileType=png,bmp
```

`JPEG` images are being returned.

Seem like my assumption is wrong. Does anyone know how to have multiple fileType for Google Custom Search API during image searching?

p/s Similar question had been raised before few years ago but no concrete answer yet : [Multiple file types search using Google Custom Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901738/multiple-file-types-search-using-google-custom-search-api)

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?fileType=jpg,png,AND OTHER TYPES YOU NEED&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&cx=GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=picasso&searchType=image
```

Comment: I think it's correct but can you give source of this answer?

Comment: This is not working for me. Getting other types as well

Comment: Can confirm that the OP is correct. I am querying for fileType=jpg,png and getting gifs in the returned result. Here's what I have tested - 1. Using one filetype e.g. `fileType=png` works perfectly. 2. Since the rights parameter uses brackets around its values and a vertical bar to separate them, I tried that. It does not work. 3. Using `jpg,png` as the value in the console on the developer site works perfectly. Typing your query directly into the browser url returns gifs again. Conclusion: there seem to be two code bases and the one publicly accessible has this bug.

Comment: im not sure why it doesn't work for you guys but it's working for me.